# Angular2 - Maximum Call Stack Exceeded error when rendering images

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image-rendering

In my Angular2 application, I want to show an image which is in Uint8Array format. But I am getting 'Maximum Call Stack Exceeded'. I could render images of size ~48Kb with no error. But when the image size is above ~300Kb is when I am getting this error. This is how I am rendering the image:

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("imagePreview")).src = "data:image/" + type + ";base64," +
                        btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, objData.Body));
```

Can someone please tell me whether I am doing it in the right way. If not, please tell me how to do it correctly

Comment: Do you have the component and the implementation?

Comment: Sorry the component and the implementation are too long to be pasted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.fromCharcode()` will run into a `maximum call stack exceeded` with large string data.

To be able to convert said object to `base64` you need to implement a loop based on the string length. Something like this comes to mind:

```
let img: HTMLInputElement = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("imagePreview"));
let bin : string = '';

for (let i = 0, l = objData.Body.length; i < l; i++) {
    bin += String.fromCharCode(objData.Body[i]);
}

img.src = "data:image/" + type + ";base64," + btoa(bin);
```

Perhaps it is more efficient to chunk up the string in bigger pieces than 1 character, but that's up to you to find the most speedy way :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with rendering base64 16K resolution image from DB, but it had nothing to do with the answer above.

That's the error I had. 
[image: that's]

As you can see it is caused by sanitization process. So in my case I had to trust the image to prevent sanitization check from running. 
This string solved the issue for me, hope that helps someone.

```
const safeUrl = domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(base64string)
```

Pass it like that

```
<img [src]="img">
```